# How to change edit text background color with LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android

I want to change the LinearLayout background color and I want to reflect the changes to the editText, but the problem is I will get two different colors. I know how to to change the background of editText, but I want to change the LinearLayout and the editText background color changes with it. When I change the layout background, the editText always gets a lighter color which is not what I want. Look at the image:

[image: editText showing lighter yellow background color that the encompassing LinearLayout]

The background of delete button and checkbox changes with the layout background but not the editText. As I said I don't want to set the background of editText on its own. May be there is a way to do with styles but it's not clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

**First : make new xml file in res/drawable name it rounded_edit_text then paste this:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <shape  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
            <solid android:color="#F9966B" />
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
                android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
        </shape>
```

//   **Second: in res/layout copy and past following code (code of EditText)**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtdoctor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edit_text"
    android:ems="10" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```